# Retrofit2 can't test with localhost:8080

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit2, okhttp

I am writing a Unit Test to test my API calls, using Retrofit2.
I have a mock of the server that I can launch locally (using localhost:8080)

I always receive a 403 error - Forbidden but it's working great with Postman

```
@Config(sdk = [28])
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MockServerTest {

    private lateinit var result: Response<CacheResult>
    private lateinit var api: FakeAPI

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        api = CompanySingleton.retrofit.create(FakeAPI::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun getResult() {
        runBlocking {
            result = api.cache()
            assertThat(result.isSuccessful, equalTo(true))
        }
    }
}


object CompanySingleton {

    private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()

            val requestBuilder = original
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth test")
                .addHeader("x-device-id", "test")

            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        ).build()

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case testing with emulators I put http://10.0.2.2:8000 to access my local host

Comment: I am not using an emulator since it's an Unit Test. I don't need a device to launch it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the api is being served on your laptop/pc (and postman definitely running on it can reach it using localhost). I think you should use the local IP of your laptop (e.g. 192.168.1.10) on android. Also don't forget to open 8080 port on your firewall (or simply turn it off)

Comment: My client eventually gave me another address. But thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

When I have to test some local service, I usually use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It's simple to run, just in terminal you type:

```
./ngrok http 3000
```